# How to identify invalid pattern using regx?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset such as below:

```
import pandas as pd

dic={"ID":[1,2,3,4,5,6],
     "Size":["3-4mm","12mm",math.nan,"1 mm","1mm, 2mm, 3mm","13*18mm"]}
dt = pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

so, the dataset is:

```
   ID           Size

   1           3-4mm
   2           12mm
   3           NaN
   4           1 mm
   5           1mm, 2mm, 3mm
   6           13*18mm
```

In the column `Size`, i should have **only 3 valid patterns**, and ***anything except these 3 are invalid***. These 3 pattern are as below

1. `3-4mm` (int-intmm)
2. `NaN`
3. `4mm` (intmm)

I am wondering how can i have function which specifies the `ID` of the rows which has invalid size pattern?

So, in my example:

```
ID

4
5
6
```

The reason is their size is not in valid format. 
I have no preference for the solution, but i guess the most easiest solution comes from `Regx`

Comment: You can try [`^\d+\s+(\d+-\d+mm|nan|\d+mm)$`](https://regex101.com/r/2rf58Q/1/)

Comment: @CodeManiac could you please write a complete answer? Also, it seems that, it selects the valid patterns, meanwhile i asked for *invalids*

Comment: So you can return true only for the values which don't match with this pattern from your filter, i am not well experienced with python syntax

Comment: someone with python experience can easily use this regex [`^(?:\d+-\d+mm|nan|\d+mm)$`](https://regex101.com/r/2rf58Q/2/) to create an answer

Comment: using @CodeManiac regex pattern, do something like: `dt.loc[~dt.Size.str.contains('^(?:\d+-\d+mm|\d+mm)$',na=True),'ID']`

Comment: @anky_91 feel free to post as an answer

Comment: @CodeManiac i actually did nothing , just used your pattern , you should post the answer :)

Comment: @anky_91 i am not familiar with python syntax so will not be able to create a answer with proper explanation about syntax, i am happy in whatever way you can go ahead and post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using @CodeManiac's pattern, you can pass it to [`series.str.contains()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and pass the `na` parameter as `True` since it is a actual NaN:

```
dt.loc[~dt.Size.str.contains('^(?:\d+-\d+mm|\d+mm)$',na=True),'ID']
```

---

```
3    4
4    5
5    6
```

Details:

executing: `dt.Size.str.contains('^(?:\d+-\d+mm|\d+mm)$')`

```
0     True
1     True
2      NaN
3    False
4    False
5    False
```

pass `na=True` to fill `NaN` as `True`:

```
dt.Size.str.contains('^(?:\d+-\d+mm|\d+mm)$',na=True)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
```

Then use invert `~` to invert `True` as `False` and vice versa since we want `False` values and call the `ID` column under [`df.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Comment: On side note:- can be further shortened to `^\d+(?:-\d+)?$`

Answer (score 1):

The function that returns `'ID'`-s of rows with invalid value in `'Size'` column:

```
import re  # standard Python regular expressions module
def get_invalid(dt):
     return dt[dt['Size'].apply(lambda r: re.match(r'^\d+-\d+mm|nan|\d+mm$', str(r), re.MULTILINE) is None)]['ID']
```

Output:

```
3    4
4    5
5    6
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

Comment: wouldn't this need `re.IGNORECASE` to match `NaN` with `nan` etc? Also, is the capturing group strictly required for a `True` / `False` match test?

Comment: Thanks. I can understand `r` but what is `re`?

Comment: @MurrayW: no, `re.IGNORECASE` is not needed because `str(math.nan)` is just `'nan'`. The capturing group of course is not needed at all.

Comment: @Jeff: `re` is standard Python module for regular expressions. Please see the updated code.

Comment: @sophros can we do same with [`dataframe.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html)  ?

Comment: @CodeManiac: how would you suggest to do it?

Comment: @sophros i am asking can we ? i am not familiar with python, i just tried to do it with dataframe.filter but couldn't so i am asking out of curosity

Comment: @CodeManiac: apologies, I took your question as a gentle nudge towards a solution that you have in mind. I am not sure the same can be done with `dataframe.filter`. I had a brief look as by its name it looks like a natural candidate but I couldn't figure out how to use it to solve this particular issue.